# How to get first three average colours of an image?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In my app i need to show first three average colors(mostly used colours) of an image . how can i get this? i hv tried the below code to get one average color but i need three colors based on its presents level . 
ex. sample output :
 Blue #0000FF
 Aqua #00FFFF
 Gray #808080

-(UIColor *)averageColor{

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char rgba[4];
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1),  given_Img.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
UIColor *colorOfArtwork;



if(rgba[3]) {
    NSLog(@"rgba[3]");
    CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
    CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;

  return colorOfArtwork = [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                                     green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                                      blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                                     alpha:alpha];
}
else {
   return colorOfArtwork =  [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                                      green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                                       blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                                      alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: like purple , yellow & whatever .

Comment: Put some code if you have tried something..

Comment: What do you mean by "based on its priority"?

Comment: which means mostly used colours.....

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableDictionary *dicColors;

loop through each pixel if entry in the dicColors then increment the value other wise add a new entry in dicColors for this color with initial value of 1.

convert to NSArray and sort

get the first 3 elements of the array. If your image is blank or solid color this array may have only 1 or 2 entries so check that too.